# Using arrays inside a custom data object (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

Assume I have a custom data object names `MyDataObject`, defined as such:

```
    public class MyDataObject
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int inx { get; set; }
    public string[] inputArr = new string[6];
}
```

I now can add `MyDataObject` to a list of objects. As shown below:

```
public void PopuList()
    {

        var items = new ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>();
        items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "foo", Checked = false, inx = 0 });
        listBox.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to add an array (`inputArr` as seen in the code above) to `MyDataObject`. `inputArr` is to have a length of 6, of which will be customized for each item. Some elements will be left blank. My attempt at getting arrays to add to the `MyDataObject` is as follows:

```
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "foo", Checked = false, inx = 0, inputArr[0] = "bar" });
```

For some reason this gives me an error across the entire `inputArr[0] = "bar"`. The error states `The name inputArr does not exist in the current context`.

I have also tried

```
items.Add(new MyDataObject() { Caption = "foo", Checked = false, inx = 0, inputArr = { "a","b","c","d","e","f" } });
```

This however gives me an error on each of the six strings. The error is: `string[] does not contain a definition for 'add'`

Any clues on adding arrays to custom data objects?

Comment: `new MyDataObject() { Caption = "foo", Checked = false, inx = 0, inputArr = new string[] { "a","b","c","d","e","f" } }`;  but if you make `inputArr` a `List<string>`, your code will work. it will be simpler to transform list `inputArr`into a property too

Comment: Arrays are so DotNet Framework 1.1'ish.  I'd suggest using IList<string> or ICollection<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array initializer:

```
items.Add(new MyDataObject() 
{ 
    Caption = "foo", 
    Checked = false, 
    inx = 0, 
    inputArr = new [] { "a","b","c","d","e","f" } 
});
```

**Note**

In the definition of `MyDataObject`, I don't see a property whose name is `Checked`. If this isn't a property of `MyDataObject`, you have to remove it from the above object initializer.